# Delete a column in a pandas' DataFrame if its sum is less than x

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to create a program that will delete a column in a Panda's dataFrame if the column's sum is less than 10.

I currently have the following solution, but I was curious if there is a more pythonic way to do this.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(AllData)
sum = df.sum(axis=1)
badCols = list()
for index in range(len(sum)):
    if sum[index]  < 10:
        badCols.append(index)
df = df.drop(df.columns[badCols], axis=1)
```

In my approach, I create a list of column indexes that have sums less than 10, then I delete this list. Is there a better approach for doing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can accomplish your objective using a one-liner by using a list comprehension and `iteritems` to identify all columns that meet your criteria.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 10], 'b': [1, 1], 'c': [20, 30]})
>>> df
    a  b   c
0   1  1  20
1  10  1  30

df.drop([col for col, val in df.sum().iteritems() if val < 10], axis=1, inplace=True)

>>> df
    a   c
0   1  20
1  10  30
```

Answer (score 24):

You can call [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) to generate a `Series` that gives the sum of each column, then use this to generate a boolean mask against your column array and use this to filter the df. DF generation code **borrowed** from @Alexander:

```
In [2]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 10], 'b': [1, 1], 'c': [20, 30]})
df

Out[2]:
    a  b   c
0   1  1  20
1  10  1  30

In [3]:    
df.sum()

Out[3]:
a    11
b     2
c    50
dtype: int64

In [6]:
df[df.columns[df.sum()>10]]

Out[6]:
    a   c
0   1  20
1  10  30
```